# Azure csi disk FailedAttachVolume issue : could not get disk name from disk URL

Tags: azure, kubernetes, persistent-volumes

I am using azure csi disk driver method for implementing K8 persistent volume. I have installed azure-csi-drivers in my K8 cluster and using below mentioned files as end-to-end testing purpose but my deployment is getting failed due to following error :

> Warning FailedAttachVolume 23s (x7 over 55s) attachdetach-controller
>   AttachVolume.Attach failed for volume "pv-azuredisk-csi" : rpc error:
>   code = NotFound desc = Volume not found, failed with error: could not
>   get disk name from
>   /subscriptions/464f9a13-7g6o-730g-hqi4-6ld2802re6z1/resourcegroups/560d_RTT_HOT_ENV_RG/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/560d-RTT-PVDisk,
>   correct format:
>   ./subscriptions/(?:.)/resourceGroups/(?:.*)/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/(.+)

Note: I have checked multiple times, my URL is correct but I am not sure if underscore in resource group name is creating any problem, RG = "560d_RTT_HOT_ENV_RG". Please suggest if anyone have any idea what is going wrong?

K8 version : 14.9
CSI drivers : v0.3.0

### My YAML files are :

```
csi-pv.yaml

apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
name: pv-azuredisk-csi
namespace: azure-static-diskpv-csi-fss
spec:
capacity:
storage: 10Gi
accessModes:
- ReadWriteOnce
persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
csi:
driver: disk.csi.azure.com
readOnly: false
volumeHandle: /subscriptions/464f9a13-7g6o-730g-hqi4-6ld2802re6z1/resourcegroups/560d_RTT_HOT_ENV_RG/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/560d-RTT-PVDisk
volumeAttributes:
cachingMode: ReadOnly
fsType: ext4
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

```
csi-pvc.yaml

kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
name: pvc-azuredisk-csi
namespace: azure-static-diskpv-csi-fss
spec:
accessModes:
- ReadWriteOnce
resources:
requests:
storage: 10Gi
volumeName: pv-azuredisk-csi
storageClassName: ""
```

---

```
nginx-csi-pod.yaml

kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
name: nginx-azuredisk-csi
namespace: azure-static-diskpv-csi-fss
spec:
nodeSelector:
beta.kubernetes.io/os: linux
containers:
image: nginx
name: nginx-azuredisk-csi
command:
"/bin/sh"
"-c"
while true; do echo $(date) >> /mnt/azuredisk/outfile; sleep 1; done
volumeMounts:
name: azuredisk01
mountPath: "/mnt/azuredisk"
volumes:
name: azuredisk01
persistentVolumeClaim:
claimName: pvc-azuredisk-csi
```

Comment: Do you try the solution in the update of my answer and does it solve your problem? Or you still need more help?

Comment: Why not give any response? Do you really want to solve the problem?!

Comment: Apologies for late response, I could not check it because I do not have privilege to change RG name. I have raised this issue to concerned authority, once it will be changed I will check and surely update you.

Comment: I think you misunderstand me. I mean you need to change the RG name into lower letters in the PV YAML file, not the azure resource. Even if the RG name contains uppercase letters.

Comment: Unfortunately changing RG in lower case did not worked . facing same error .I changed my disk URL to : /subscriptions/464f9a13-7g6o-730g-hqi4-6ld2802re6z1/resourcegroups/560d_rtt_hot_env_rg/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/560d-RTT-PVDisk      and next time : /subscriptions/464f9a13-7g6o-730g-hqi4-6ld2802re6z1/resourcegroups/560d_rtt_hot_env_rg/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/560d-rtt-pvdisk  , non of them worked .

Comment: You do not need to change the disk name into lower letters, only the group name is case sensitive.

Comment: See the update in my answer.

Comment: In my first trial I did same , I changed only RG name in lower case : /subscriptions/464f9a13-7g6o-730g-hqi4-6ld2802re6z1/resourcegroups/560d_rtt_hot_env_rg/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/560d-RTT-PVDisk  but got same error . As I mentioned in my 11th dec comment that I did not do CSI drivers sanity check after setting up them , should I think that there may be any problem in CSI driver setup ?

Comment: Do you use AKS or other Kubernetes? And do you install CSI driver before you use it?

Comment: No I am not using AKS , I have created native kubernetes using Azure VMs and yes first I installed CSI drivers following : "https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/azuredisk-csi-driver/blob/master/docs/install-csi-driver-v0.3.0.md" link and then tried to run this example. But I did not do sanity check for CSI drivers ,Is it necessary to do it ?

Comment: Now I know that we use different environments, I make the test in AKS, but according to my experience, do a sanity check for CSI drivers is necessary.

Comment: Would you please refer me a good reference from where I can get how to do sanity check for CSI drivers .I refered "https://github.com/kubernetes-csi/csi-test/tree/master/cmd/csi-sanity"  link but could not get thinks in right way .No error ,No success .

Comment: How do you install the Kubernetes in Azure VM? Why not use the AKS cluster? You would not meet such errors with AKS.

Comment: It was our client choice , I suggested him AKS but finally he chooses  Native K8 cluster .

Comment: Which tutorial do you follow to create the kubernetes cluster?

Comment: K8 cluster was created by client's infra team as vanilla deployment of k8s with Chef cookbook .My responsibility is to configure this K8 for micro-service deployment.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you create the disk in another resource group, not the AKS nodes group. So you must grant the Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) service principal for your cluster the `Contributor` role to the disk's resource group firstly. For more details, see [Create an Azure disk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-disk-volume#create-an-azure-disk).

**Update:**

Finally, I found out the reason why it cannot find the volume. I think it's a stupid definition. It's case sensitive about the resource Id of the disk which you used for the persist volume. So you need to change your csi-pv.yaml file like below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv-azuredisk-csi
  namespace: azure-static-diskpv-csi-fss
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  csi:
    driver: disk.csi.azure.com
    readOnly: false
    volumeHandle: /subscriptions/464f9a13-7g6o-730g-hqi4-6ld2802re6z1/resourcegroups/560d_rtt_hot_env_rg/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/560d-RTT-PVDisk
    volumeAttributes:
      cachingMode: ReadOnly
      fsType: ext4
```

In addition, the first paragraph of the answer is also important.

**Update:**

Here are the screenshots of the result that the static disk for the CSI driver works on my side:

[image]

[image]

Comment: how do you arrive to that conclusion?

Comment: @4c74356b41 The error shows the disk group and the information in the link.

Comment: it says not found, not failed to authenticate, and there is no link. apart from that it specifically talks about wrong uri format\failing to parse uri

Comment: @ Charles Xu : Both K8 Vms and Disk are from same Resource Group .One thing more I installed azure disk CSI drivers on my K8 and deployment seems OK but I did not do sanity check for drivers.

Comment: @goldench Update the answer and it will work for you. If you solve the problem with my answer please mark it.

Comment: @goldench What about your question? Do you solve it?